# Conditional Push ini Parse.com and IOS 8

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am working on ios app using parse.com as backend.I am using swift.
I required to send condition to other users using push or if other better way ie. I invite friend through push notification if friend accept the invitation he will add in my circle otherwise not. How do I do that? Or if any other idea you have share with me.

Comment: You can use channels to target push messages using parse, have you tried anything? did you even get push to work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, push notification work perfectly. My friend get push but he is getting only message box with Dismiss button but I need condition there, Like "Do you want to accept the invitation?", yes/no button.if he accept the invitation he will added in my friend circle otherwise not.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you need to override didReceiveRemoteNotification in your AppDelegate. You can find plenty of examples online

Comment: Also can i get response back from the friend what he made accept or reject? should i use parse cloud code for that?

Comment: Yep it's pretty simple

Comment: How can I get that response back from the friend? I need to store the response in parse table or else? I new to parse.com.